# apply plugin: 'com.amazonaws.appsync' detected as trojan

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-appsync, trojan

I am developing some personal project and I'm learning how to use aws. When I first ran the app it showed a warning which says the app is a threat, the details shows that it's trojan with a Risk name: **Android:Evo-gen [Trj]|+Ag1386570|egap**. So I went and commented every possible code that is causing it and it turns out that apply plugin: 'com.amazonaws.appsync' in my app-level build.gradle is causing it.

How do I fix this? I can't find any forum about this issue. Hoping to get some response, thanks

Comment: what is'it'? anti-virus?

Comment: @Asdfg so I have a Vivo phone and it's just says it's from "iManager" some default on Vivo. Should I be worried or is it cool?